# Need to get previous financial year data in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

How can i write SQL which will fetch the data for last year.
e.g. if i run this sql today (07-02-2020) so it should give me sum of lcy_amt data from 01-01-2019 to 31-12-2019;

```
trn_date      lcy_amount

08-01-2020    200
08-01-2019    100
02-11-2020    150
```

Please assist.

Comment: What exactly are you having problems with? Do you know how to get sums? Do you know how to get rows from last year? What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compare the `YEAR` part of `trn_date` with one less than the `YEAR` of the current date e.g.

```
SELECT SUM(lcy_amount)
FROM yourtable
WHERE EXTRACT(year FROM trn_date) = EXTRACT(year FROM SYSDATE) - 1
```

To allow for use of indexes, it might be more efficient to use this query. Note that it relies on the values in `trn_date` having no time component; if they do then the query in @Tejash answer is more appropriate.

```
SELECT SUM(lcy_amount)
FROM yourtable
WHERE trn_date BETWEEN TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'YEAR') - INTERVAL '1' YEAR AND
       TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'YEAR') - INTERVAL '1' DAY
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d36f3/12)

Comment: if i run this sql query so it will give me the data from 2019 to till date. But i want the data only for 2019 ,i.e( 01-01-2019 to 31-12-2019).

Comment: @satyaKumari this will only give you data from 2019. If you also want data from years prior to 2019, change the `=` to `<=`

Comment: @satyaKumari if you want data for 2019 **and** 2020, change the `=` to `>=`

Comment: if i run this sql query so it will give me the data from 2019 to till date. But i want the data only for 2019 ,i.e( 01-01-2019 to 31-12-2019).

Comment: @satya Kumari: You are wrong. The query gives you the data from 2019 only.

Comment: @satyaKumari no, this will only give you results for 2019. See http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d36f3/1

Comment: I think your last query will exclude transactions of 31-dec-2019

Comment: `TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'YEAR') - INTERVAL '1' DAY` = `31-Dec-2019 00:00:00` and what about the `trn_date ` = `31-Dec-2019 01:00:00`? I hope you got my point. You must use `trunc(trn_date)` in `WHERE` clause

Comment: @Tejash I see what you mean but  none of the `trn_date` values in the question have times

Comment: Ok @Nick. I was just trying to explain the full proof solution. Anyway, you are a genius and I respect you a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You can use following query:

```
SELECT SUM(lcy_amount)
FROM yourtable
WHERE trn_date >= TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'YEAR') - INTERVAL '1' YEAR 
  AND trn_date < TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'YEAR')
```

The second query in the @nick's answer will exclude the 31-dec-2019 as it should be `WHERE trunc(trn_date) ...` else `trn_date = 31-dec-2019 00:00:01 to 31-dec-2019 23:59:59` will be excluded from the result.

Cheers!!

Comment: This is safest if the `trn_date` values have times.

Comment: @SatyaKumari . . . This is the better solution because it allows Oracle to use an index on `trn_date` (or to prune a partition).